# replace xml node from bottom to top

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i have an xml that contains 2 nodes that are equal. i would replace the 1st node that is on top with the node that is on bottom and remove the 2nd node. the 2 nodes are named "ApplicationArea" and contained childs. now the 2nd node contains the original information that i need to replace at the top and remove from the xml on the bottom

my xml is

```
<SyncShipment versionID="2.6.3" Release="9.2">
<ApplicationArea>
<Sender>
<LogicalID>lid://infor.dbconnector</LogicalID>
<ComponentID>Visual</ComponentID>
<ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
</Sender>
<CreationDateTime>2015-03-04T09:25:12.107Z</CreationDateTime>
<BODID>infor-nid:infor:Shipper~S14-01709:?Shipment&verb=Sync</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
<Sync>
<TenantID>infor</TenantID>
<AccountingEntityID>NKFEX</AccountingEntityID>
<LocationID>Site~Gouda</LocationID>
<ActionCriteria>
<ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
</ActionCriteria>
</Sync>
<Shipment>
<ShipmentHeader>
<DocumentID>Shipper~S14-01709</DocumentID>
<UserArea>
<Property>
<NameValue type="String" name="UDF1">external info</NameValue>
</Property>
<Property>
<NameValue type="xml" name="sourceAA">
<ApplicationArea>
<Sender>
<LogicalID schemeVersionID="VMSHPENT:7.0.0.156:AC7726D2">lid://infor.visual.visual</Logical ID>
<ComponentID>Visual</ComponentID>
<ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
</Sender>
<CreationDateTime>2015-03-04T09:25:12.107Z</CreationDateTime>
<BODID schemeAgencyName="Visual" location="Site~Gouda">infor-nid:infor:NKFEX:Site~Gouda:Shipper~S14-01709~1:?Shipment&verb=Sync</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
</NameValue>
</Property>
</UserArea>
</ShipmentHeader>
<ShipmentItem>
<ItemID>pippo</ItemID>
</ShipmentItem>
</Shipment>
</DataArea>
</SyncShipment>
```

after the transformation it should be like this

```
<SyncShipment versionID="2.6.3" Release="9.2">
<ApplicationArea>
<Sender>
<LogicalID schemeVersionID="VMSHPENT:7.0.0.156:AC7726D2">lid://infor.visual.visual</LogicalID>
<ComponentID>Visual</ComponentID>
<ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
</Sender>
<CreationDateTime>2015-03-04T09:25:12.107Z</CreationDateTime>
<BODID schemeAgencyName="Visual" location="Site~Gouda">infor-nid:infor:NKFEX:Site~Gouda:Shipper~S14-01709~1:?Shipment&verb=Sync</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
<Sync>
<TenantID>infor</TenantID>
<AccountingEntityID>NKFEX</AccountingEntityID>
<LocationID>Site~Gouda</LocationID>
<ActionCriteria>
<ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
</ActionCriteria>
</Sync>
<Shipment>
<ShipmentHeader>
<DocumentID>Shipper~S14-01709</DocumentID>
<UserArea>
<Property>
<NameValue type="String" name="UDF1">external info</NameValue>
</Property>
</UserArea>
</ShipmentHeader>
<ShipmentItem>
<ItemID>pippo</ItemID>
</ShipmentItem>
</Shipment>
</DataArea>
</SyncShipment>
```

can you help me on this?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you've tried? What are you using to perform the transform? XSLT?

Comment: Hello Daniel, i have no idea how to do that, i was thinking about using a variable but i'm not confident how it works

Comment: A variable in what language?

Comment: i mean variable in xslt like <xsl:variable name="varname" select="xpath"/>

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how I'd do this with XSLT. I'm using what's called a push approach. This means I'm using `xsl:apply-templates` to push the data through and allowing templates to match as needed.

The most important template in this XSLT is the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying). It copies all attributes and nodes (text, element, comment and processing instructions) as is.

I override the identity transform with 2 other templates. One for `SyncShipment` and one for `Property`.

The template that matches `SyncShipment` outputs a copy of the `SyncShipment` element and then does 3 `xsl:apply-templates` to push through the data that we want:

- the attributes of the current context (`SyncShipment`)
- the `ApplicationArea` that is a descendant of `DataArea`
- any other nodes that aren't `ApplicationArea` (this means the first `ApplicationArea` is not going to be processed)

We use 3 different `xsl:apply-templates` here so that we get the order that we want. There is a comment in the XSLT that shows how this can be done easier in XSLT 2.0. If the order doesn't matter at all, you can also use this instead of the three `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|DataArea//ApplicationArea|node()[not(self::ApplicationArea)]"/>
```

The template that matches `Property` only matches `Property`'s that have a child `NameValue` that has a child `ApplicationArea`. The template is empty so no further processing is done. (Nothing is output.)

Here's the example:

**XML** (corrected to be [well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-well-formed))

```
<SyncShipment versionID="2.6.3" Release="9.2">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <Sender>
            <LogicalID>lid://infor.dbconnector</LogicalID>
            <ComponentID>Visual</ComponentID>
            <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
        </Sender>
        <CreationDateTime>2015-03-04T09:25:12.107Z</CreationDateTime>
        <BODID>infor-nid:infor:Shipper~S14-01709:?Shipment&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Sync>
            <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
            <AccountingEntityID>NKFEX</AccountingEntityID>
            <LocationID>Site~Gouda</LocationID>
            <ActionCriteria>
                <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
            </ActionCriteria>
        </Sync>
        <Shipment>
            <ShipmentHeader>
                <DocumentID>Shipper~S14-01709</DocumentID>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue type="String" name="UDF1">external info</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue type="xml" name="sourceAA">
                            <ApplicationArea>
                                <Sender>
                                    <LogicalID schemeVersionID="VMSHPENT:7.0.0.156:AC7726D2"
                                        >lid://infor.visual.visual</LogicalID>
                                    <ComponentID>Visual</ComponentID>
                                    <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
                                </Sender>
                                <CreationDateTime>2015-03-04T09:25:12.107Z</CreationDateTime>
                                <BODID schemeAgencyName="Visual" location="Site~Gouda"
                                    >infor-nid:infor:NKFEX:Site~Gouda:Shipper~S14-01709~1:?Shipment&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
                            </ApplicationArea>
                        </NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </ShipmentHeader>
            <ShipmentItem>
                <ItemID>pippo</ItemID>
            </ShipmentItem>
        </Shipment>
    </DataArea>
</SyncShipment>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SyncShipment">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--
            If using XSLT 2.0, all three xsl:apply-templates could
            be replaced with: 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,
                DataArea//ApplicationArea,
                node()[not(self::ApplicationArea)]"/>
            -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="DataArea//ApplicationArea"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ApplicationArea)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Property[NameValue/ApplicationArea]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<SyncShipment versionID="2.6.3" Release="9.2">
   <ApplicationArea>
      <Sender>
         <LogicalID schemeVersionID="VMSHPENT:7.0.0.156:AC7726D2">lid://infor.visual.visual</LogicalID>
         <ComponentID>Visual</ComponentID>
         <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
      </Sender>
      <CreationDateTime>2015-03-04T09:25:12.107Z</CreationDateTime>
      <BODID schemeAgencyName="Visual" location="Site~Gouda">infor-nid:infor:NKFEX:Site~Gouda:Shipper~S14-01709~1:?Shipment&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
   </ApplicationArea>
   <DataArea>
      <Sync>
         <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
         <AccountingEntityID>NKFEX</AccountingEntityID>
         <LocationID>Site~Gouda</LocationID>
         <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
         </ActionCriteria>
      </Sync>
      <Shipment>
         <ShipmentHeader>
            <DocumentID>Shipper~S14-01709</DocumentID>
            <UserArea>
               <Property>
                  <NameValue type="String" name="UDF1">external info</NameValue>
               </Property>
            </UserArea>
         </ShipmentHeader>
         <ShipmentItem>
            <ItemID>pippo</ItemID>
         </ShipmentItem>
      </Shipment>
   </DataArea>
</SyncShipment>
```